# How to make GenParameterSpec for Elliptic Curve Diffie–Hellman?

Tags: java, android, security

java.security.spec provides ECGenParameterSpec for Elliptic Curve and DHGenParameterSpec for Diffie–Hellman. But how to generate Spec for ECDH? I need **2048bit MODP Group** for *DH* and **secp256r1** for *EC*.

```
ECGenParameterSpec ecParamSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1");    
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDH", "SC");
kpg.initialize(ecParamSpec);
KeyPair kpClient = kpg.generateKeyPair();
```

How can I configure DH group ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use BouncyCastle, use [`ECNamedCurveTable`](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/prov/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/jce/ECNamedCurveTable.java). And [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/0280__Diffie-Hellman.htm) are multiple approaches to DH.